# Perform mathematical calculations inside string formatting

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, string-formatting, number-formatting

I want to convert a number indicating seconds to my specific format **mmmm:ss** for example the number 3601 should result to 60:01 and 7201 results to 1200:01

For this purpose I have written the below code

```
var text = string.Format("{0}:{1}",seconds / 60, seconds % 60);
//seconds 651 outputs 10:51
//seconds 6612 outputs 110:12
```

which works fine, I just need to make a format out of this, something like

```
var text = string.Format("{x:x/60:x%60},seconds);
```

Is it possible to make custom formats? I insist on being done as a formatted string because I want to set it on a `DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Format` property, where I could not inject code.

Comment: Insisting won't help. You have to work within the realm to of possible.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan :) maybe I used the wrong word, English is not my mother tongue. So you say it is impossible to do that as a Format?

Comment: Any reason for not doing it `CellFomatting` event?

Comment: Yes good reason, I was not aware of that event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event for formatting the time value.

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == ColumnIndex)
    {
        e.Value = // formatted value
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```